# How to get the WorkItemField type, whether it is text box or dropdown or text area ? in VSTS

Tags: typescript, azure-devops

```
WiClient.getWorkItem(originWI).then((workitem) => {});
```

I am getting workitem field refrence name and value from above api.
I want to know what kind of field is it? Whether text or text area or drop-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the REST API: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=vsts-rest-4.1) to get the field reference name and value.

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=4.1
```

And to get the work item field type you can call this REST API : [Fields - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/fields/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1)

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/wit/fields/{fieldNameOrRefName}?api-version=4.1
```

You can reference below articles:

- [Using TypeScript for your VSTS extension walk trough](http://www.ericksegaar.com/2017/11/27/using-typescript-for-your-vsts-extension-walk-trough/)
- [Call a REST API from your extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/call-rest-api?view=vsts)
- Sample: [VSTS-Extension-ScrumReport](https://github.com/mikaelkrief/VSTS-Extension-ScrumReport/blob/master/ScrumReport/scripts/app.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `getWorkItemTypeField()` or `getWorkItemTypeFields()` method in [WorkItemTrackingProcessDefinitionsApi](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-node-api/blob/master/api/WorkItemTrackingProcessDefinitionsApi.ts) to get this information.